# How do I use an if statement in Rails validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to create a validation statement that validates an object if `service_area` is present UNLESS `service_area_radius==0`

Here's the statement I created, which doesn't work:

```
validates :service_area, :presence => true, unless: "service_area_radius==0"
```

Comment: An error message would be really useful. You're also mixing 1.8 (hash rocket => ) and 1.9 (colon) style syntax which isn't a problem  but just makes it harder to visually parse

Comment: You are trying to validate the service_area ONLY IF the service_area_radius is present? right ?

Answer (score 0):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations

Like this:

```
validates_presence_of :password, :if => :should_validate_password?
validates_presence_of :country
validates_presence_of :state, :if => :in_us?
attr_accessor :updating_password

def in_us?
  country == 'US'
end

def should_validate_password?
  updating_password || new_record?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :service_area,
     presence:  {message: "Area Radius is missing."}, if: :radius_found?

private 
 def radius_found? 
    service_area_radius > 0
 end
```

1. The validation for service_area will be executed if radius_found? returns true.
2. radius_found? will return true when the service_area_radius(attribute) hold value > 0.
3. Adding a custom message with message: option, when the validation fails.